# Highcharts XRange datetime format

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, highcharts

I want to create a xrange highcharts. According to this [demo](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/x-range), they create date using UTC format, but my json output from MySQL are something like this

```
[{"y":1,"x":"2018-01-19 08:10:57","x2":"2018-01-19 10:18:04"},
 {"y":3,"x":"2018-01-19 07:39:55","x2":"2018-01-19 08:21:01"},
 {"y":2,"x":"2018-01-19 13:06:46","x2":"2018-01-19 14:30:49"},
 {"y":4,"x":"2018-01-19 10:23:44","x2":"2018-01-19 11:54:48"},
 {"y":2,"x":"2018-01-19 08:10:05","x2":"2018-01-19 09:15:12"},
 {"y":4,"x":"2018-01-19 09:00:16","x2":"2018-01-19 10:03:20"},
 {"y":4,"x":"2018-01-19 08:10:49","x2":"2018-01-19 08:50:53"},
 {"y":5,"x":"2018-01-19 08:07:15","x2":"2018-01-19 09:04:21"},
 {"y":3,"x":"2018-01-19 08:30:22","x2":"2018-01-19 09:28:25"}]
```

How to change the format, to make the chart working? Please help, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the `x` and `x2` values to be either `Date.UTC(...)` or a `unix timestamp` in milliseconds.

In php you can reformat you data in the following way:

```
<?php

$data = json_decode('[
    {"y":1,"x":"2018-01-19 08:10:57","x2":"2018-01-19 10:18:04"},
    {"y":3,"x":"2018-01-19 07:39:55","x2":"2018-01-19 08:21:01"},
    {"y":2,"x":"2018-01-19 13:06:46","x2":"2018-01-19 14:30:49"},
    {"y":4,"x":"2018-01-19 10:23:44","x2":"2018-01-19 11:54:48"},
    {"y":2,"x":"2018-01-19 08:10:05","x2":"2018-01-19 09:15:12"},
    {"y":4,"x":"2018-01-19 09:00:16","x2":"2018-01-19 10:03:20"},
    {"y":4,"x":"2018-01-19 08:10:49","x2":"2018-01-19 08:50:53"},
    {"y":5,"x":"2018-01-19 08:07:15","x2":"2018-01-19 09:04:21"},
    {"y":3,"x":"2018-01-19 08:30:22","x2":"2018-01-19 09:28:25"}
]');

array_map(function ($d) {
    $d->x = (new DateTime($d->x, new DateTimeZone('UTC')))->getTimestamp() * 1000;
    $d->x2 = (new DateTime($d->x2, new DateTimeZone('UTC')))->getTimestamp() * 1000;
}, $data);

$data = json_encode($data);

print_r($data);
```

That gives the output of:

```
[{"y":1,"x":1516349457000,"x2":1516357084000},
{"y":3,"x":1516347595000,"x2":1516350061000},
{"y":2,"x":1516367206000,"x2":1516372249000},
{"y":4,"x":1516357424000,"x2":1516362888000},
{"y":2,"x":1516349405000,"x2":1516353312000},
{"y":4,"x":1516352416000,"x2":1516356200000},
{"y":4,"x":1516349449000,"x2":1516351853000},
{"y":5,"x":1516349235000,"x2":1516352661000},
{"y":3,"x":1516350622000,"x2":1516354105000}]
```

See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g4kn4u32/6/)** with your reformatted data.

Answer (score 0):

Re-parsing your date row data with your timezone server UTC Configuration

Example

```
 $date_string="2014-10-20 00:00:00";     
 $dateUTC = new DateTime($date_string, new DateTimeZone('Asia/Jakarta'));
 echo $dt->getTimestamp() * 1000; 
 //result will be 1413738000000
```

and check on the browser console and typing:

```
new Date(1413738000000)
```

The result will be :

> Mon Oct 20 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (WIB)

It match